# Django send data to Database: NOT NULL constraint failed: sms_post.author_id

Tags: django, django-models, migration

I am new to django, I migrated my models, the database is working fine, i can see the data that I added by the manage.py shell. But I cant add Data from my webApp. When I wrote text on the fields and press the submit button it gave me this error `NOT NULL constraint failed: sms_post.author_id`
Thanks for helping..

models.py files

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

THE_GENDER = [
    ("Monsieur", "Monsieur"),
    ("Madame", "Madame")
]


class Post(models.Model):


    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=THE_GENDER)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py files

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper


class post_form(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(post_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["name", "email", "gender", "number"]
```

views.py files

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import post_form


from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def home(request):
    form = post_form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    context = {
        "form": form
    }


    return render(request, "sms/home.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set the `author` of the instance in your for to a `User` object. You can do this with:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = post_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-view')
    else:
        form = post_form()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'sms/home.html', context)
```

In order to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), in case of a *successful* POST request, you should make a redirect, for example to the same view. You thus can here replace *`'name-of-view'`* with the name of a view to redirect to.

Comment: Thanks you for the help sir. Working FIne!